# onClick rolling number animations in javascript

Tags: javascript, random, generator, rolling-computation

im starting to figure out how I can do rolling numbers animation in javascript onClick.

So basically I have:

```
const button = document.getElementById("generate");

button.onclick = function generate(){

const randomNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1);

const el = document.getElementById('ranNum');

el.innerHTML = randomNum;
}
```

And what I would like to do is have numbers from from their current position if the person pressing a button and got 2434 and the next time the press the button the next answer would be like 132, but there would be a rolling up animation to get the next number of 132, and so on..

I seen this on google when I asked for a number generator, and their animation was sick. But sadly no documentation on googles scrolling numbers.

Does anyone have any ideas where I can go try and find documentation?

Thanks!

Comment: @code Since `Math.random` can theoretically return `0`, there is a difference between the two options.

Comment: @SebastianSimon right, so the main difference is that `Math.ceil` is upper inclusive, while `Math.floor` isn't. Okay, that works.